# "elven slices" - What is the real name (if any)?

Tags: dessert, language

In the video game "Sacred" (2004), the player can find recipes. They are usually written in a fantasy-like manner. In the German version I found a recipe called "Elfische Schnitten aus Tyr-Hadar" ("elven slices of/from Tyr-Hadar"). I was curious and tried it out. Here is the description, roughly translated from German:

> Take 8 tablespoonful of honey and heat it up to make it liquid. Add 12
>   egg yolks of hard boiled eggs. Add pepper and 175g bread crumbs. Mix
>   everything with an egg whisk until you get a homogeneous mass. Form a
>   block and let it cool down. Cut it into slices. [...]

That's how it looks like (I used a bit too much bread crumbs / too little honey, so it's quite crumbly):

[image]
[image]

It tastes sweet, much like regular cake.

**Is there any real-life recipe for this? If yes, how is this food called?**

Comment: So... it's sweetened egg yolks coated in breadcrumbs? Is it baked? Fried? Uncooked other than the egg yolks being hard boiled already?

Comment: Uncooked (except the eggs of course), just as the recipe says.

Comment: The reason I asked if you cooked it is because "let it cool down" doesn't make sense... the honey being warm isn't going to heat up the 12 egg yolks and bread crumbs much.

Comment: I think the point of heating it up is to make mixing easier, and the point of letting it cool down is to get a more solid loaf to serve (if you take a type of honey that is more solid and less liquid in room temperature). At least I noticed a difference in solidness of the loaf between freshly made (warm) and cooled down.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Do you have an image of what the slices look like?

Comment: I'm curious what German word translated as "cuboid".

Comment: It almost sounds like a sweet take on a Scotch egg, except it's not fried... I'm _very_ interested to hear how it tastes!

Comment: @JoshuaEngel "forme einen *Quader*"... "block"  or "brick" would perhaps be the more colloquial choice.

Comment: @Erica I was thinking a croquette but not fried, too... I even found recipes for "egg croquettes" but again, they're fried or at least baked.

Comment: Looks a bit like a treacle tart filling. The cooked egg yolks are a bit odd though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has got to be a completely made up recipe.

Comment: This would really be a better answer if you explained *why* you think this. I know it's hard to prove a negative, but probably best to at least explain your thought process.

Comment: I don't have anything substantial to add to my answer. I was a chef for 10 years, have traveled the world and eaten and studied the human foods from many cultures. I have never seen a use of dry cooked egg yolks, outside of polonaise sauce, some rare Chinese buns with salted yolks, or the very direct use of eggs boiled in the shell (e.g. boiled eggs, sliced boiled egg, egg mayonnaise, goldenrod, etc.). Based on my intuition I think it is painfully obvious that the video game reference was an attempt to create a completely unique recipe.